# Flutter - white spaces displaying for grid view cell in landscape mode

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, android-gridview, removing-whitespace

i have a problem to get ride of a white space in grid view cell in fluter, especially when the device is in landscape orientation, the code is :

```
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: recipesList.length,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
      mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
      //childAspectRatio: 1, 
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      Recipe recipe = recipesList[index];
      return Dismissible(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  color: Colors.white,
  elevation: 5,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){},
    child: Column(
      // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(
            'images/${recipe.picture}',
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  //margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '${recipe.id} - ${recipe.title}',
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'by Unknown Chef',
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.grey[400],
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.grey[400],
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: recipe.isFavorite
                    ? Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red)
                    : Icon(Icons.favorite_outline_outlined,
                        color: Colors.grey),
                iconSize: 36,
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
          );
    },
  ),
);
```

the result is fine as below:

[image]

but in landscape mode it's not what i want

[image]

the desired result would be like this

[image]

How can I make this cards to look like this in landscape orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `childAspectRatio` is `1.0` meaning `width = height`. If you want to get the expected result, wrap your container in `Expanded` widget and remove `Image` height property as following

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    child: Image.asset(
      'images/${recipe.picture}',
      width: double.infinity,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: i tried this modification and it works,thank you.